# Using Subqueries, "Stuff", "For XML Path" in a Joined View

Tags: sql, sql-server, subquery, for-xml-path

I am having an SQL View which shows a 
Barcodenumber (k.t_cbcde), a Deliverynotenumber (k.t_dino), a Receiptnumber (k.t_rcno), Suppliernumber (k.t_sfbp), Receiptdate (k.t_crdt) and an Ordernumber (c.t_orno).

There can be multiple Ordernumbers for one Receiptnumber and multiple Receiptnumbers for one Barcodenumbers.

Included Tables: 
    `dbo.twhinh310101 with alias k`
    `dbo.twhinh312101 with alias c`

This is a simple join which shows following results:

```
k.t_cbcde as Barcodenumber, k.t_dino as Deliverynotenumber, k.t_rcno as Receiptnumber, k.t_sfbp as Suppliernumber, k.t_crdt as Receiptdate,
c.t_orno as Ordernumber

from
dbo.twhinh310101 k
left join  dbo.twhinh312101 as c
on c.t_rcno = k.t_rcno


where k.t_cbcde = '0143797546'
```

I am using Barcodenumber 0143797546 as an example.

This is the result of that Query:[result 01](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ZPv7Y.png)

The Goal is, to have the Receiptnumbers and all the Receiptnumbers in one line. 
Like that:

[result03](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SC23g.png)

I have written a Query already but it doesn't work properly:

```
SELECT DISTINCT sub
Barcodenumber,
Delieverynotenumber,
Receiptnumber,
Suppliernumber,
Receiptdate,
Ordernumber 
= STUFF (
    (SELECT ',' + t_orno
    FROM dbo.twhinh312101 a, 
    WHERE (what to use here?)
    GROUP BY t_orno
    ORDER BY t_orno ASC
    FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '')

FROM (

SELECT DISTINCT 
    k2.t_cbcde AS Barcodenumber,
    k2.t_dino AS Delieverynotenumber,
    Receiptnumber
    = STUFF (
        (SELECT ',' + t_rcno
         FROM dbo.twhinh310101 k1
         WHERE k1.t_cbcde = k2.t_cbcde
         GROUP BY t_rcno
         ORDER BY t_rcno ASC
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
         ),
    k2.t_sfbp AS Suppliernumber, 
    k2.t_crdt AS Receiptdate,
    t_orno = STUFF (
        (SELECT  ',' + t_orno 
         FROM dbo.twhinh312101
         WHERE t_rcno = k2.t_rcno
         GROUP BY t_orno
         ORDER BY t_orno ASC
         FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, ''
        )

    FROM
    dbo.twhinh310101 k2
    left join  dbo.twhinh312101 AS c ON c.t_rcno = k2.t_rcno

    where k2.t_cbcde = '0143797546'

    )sub
```

I appreciate every help :)

here the top ten rows of the two Tables:
The Table is too large for the text Editor thats why i am using pictures

[dbo.twhinh310101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gW8tq.png)
[dbo.twhinh312101](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3IrE6.png)

If you need more information, just let me know :)

I added the two Tables in sqlfiddel: http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/153bb0/3

Hope it helps

Comment: Hi and welcome to SO. It would be very helpful if you could provide some details of your table. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query

Comment: Hi thank you for your comment. I attached the top 10 results of that table. Is there something more which is needed?

Comment: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-on-so-when-asking-a-question/285557#285557

Comment: I added the two Tables in SQL Fiddle

Comment: What should the output be for the sample data in your fiddle?